# How can I manipulate nested object in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to update one index among 3 options how can I manipulate them depends on option that a user clicked on the UI

## CODES

```
[{
    future: false,
    NumberOfDay: 0,
    HourOption: ""
  },
 {
    within_date: false,
    start_date: "",
    end_date: ""
  },
 {
    indefinitely: false
}]
```

## Expected output

in case user select the first option `future and numberOfDay would be`  changed and output might look like the following on `index one of`  this array

```
[{
    future: true,
    NumberOfDay: Entered_Number_From_User,
    HourOption: ""
  },
 {
    within_date: false,
    start_date: "",
    end_date: ""
  },
 {
    indefinitely: false
}]
```

in case user selects the second option on the UI

## Output will be

```
[{
    future: false,
    NumberOfDay: 0,
    HourOption: ""
  },
 {
    within_date: true,
    start_date: `SELECTED_DATE_FROM_UI`,
    end_date: `SELECTED_DATE_FROM_UI`
  },
 {
    indefinitely: false
}]
```

Comment: That's a rather odd data structure, do you know that the object you want to manipulate will always exist? and will it always be the first item in the array?

Comment: Sorry, your description was a bit confusing for me. You have an option (or options?) in the UI? when it is clicked, you want to change this array of objects, and pass it as a prop? Am I right?

Comment: Other options will will be selected as well in fact I edited question to make it more understandable